# Table class for tables that, when too wide split all their cells into rows

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out what HTML / CSS I need to get a certain breaking behavior depending on how much space is available. Basically, I want to have a long line of text automatically break at certain places, and all at one), when there is no longer space for it.

**Example 1:**

- There is enough horizontal space for the entire line of text:

  [image]
- There isn't enough horizontal space for the whole line (but even if there is space for the first two items, everything ends up on its own line)
  [image]

**Example 2:** This is the same as the previous example, yet it shows that I'd like to be able to use this in a nested fashion too:

- There is enough horizontal space for the entire line of text:

  [image]
- There is just not enough horizontal space for the entire line, so each cell goes onto its own line

  [image]
- There is not enough horizontal space for the second cell

  [image]

I'm looking for a solution that uses only HTML and CSS (or only uses JavaScript very lightly) since my intended use-case is to use this pretty heavily in automatically generated HTML documentation pages.

I've come across examples like [these](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_mediaquery), but I'm not sure I see how to make this work for subitems (and how to make this work without assigning a fixed size to each cell - I want to the cell-size to be determined by its content).

## Clarfiying edit

Just bringing extra emphasis to a crucial part of the question which has been overlooked. **I never want to find myself in a state where there are two items on one line and the third item on the next line. The three items should go straight from being all on one line to all on separate lines.**

Comment: That example from w3schools is making use of media queries to change the layout when the viewport is resized to a certain dimension. You can make use of flexbox or CSS grid to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Are we allowed to use JavaScript?

Comment: @Amjo Yes, but the bounty will go to the solution that is not JavaScript intensive.

Comment: @Alec, what you are trying to achieve cannot be done without Javasript. You can very easily fake it with the example's static content using media queries, but probably this is not what you need, right? Also does it matter to you if the content fills up its parent container (or browser window)?

Comment: @SUB-HDR The question also mentions I intend to use this heavily in generated HTML documentation, so your solution is not feasible - I'd have to go and manually figure out a bunch of lengths to put in `@media screen and (max-width: ...)`. Note that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47823932/3072788) answer and another answer which has since been deleted took that same approach as you did. I'm sorry if this wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As I have already stated in the comments, what the OP is looking for cannot be achieved without the use of Javascript, so here is what I came up with.

Initially we have a normal table structure, we calculate each table's width and apply a `data-width` attribute on each table - parent or nested.

On resize, as soon as each table is longer than the window width, it changes its contents display from `table-cell` to `block`, thus stacking all children.

As soon as the window width is expanded it is compared to each table's `data-width` attribute and when it fits, it expands.

edit: I thought for some reason it wouldn't work under some cases, but it actually works, so I remove the bloat!

HTML:

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="cell">
    Content 1
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="cell">
        Content 1
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Cont
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Content 3
      </div>    
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    Content 3Content 3Content 3
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid #e4e5e7;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #e4e5e7;
}

.cell .table {
  margin-bottom: -2px;
}

.table.wrap {
  white-space: normal;
}

.table.wrap > .cell {
  display: block;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('.table').each(function(i) {
  tw = 0;
  $(this).children('.cell').each(function() {
    tw += $(this).outerWidth(true);
  });
  $(this).attr('data-width', tw);
});

$(window).on('load resize', function() {
  w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
  $('.table').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).width() >= w) {
      $(this).addClass('wrap');
    } else if (w >= $(this).attr('data-width')) {
      $(this).removeClass('wrap');    
    }
  });
}).resize();
```

And here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scooterlord/g6d7w8pk/1/)

Comment: Just remember OP doesn't want a full JS solution :)

Comment: Touché! :) yes I do remember, but it should be rather working with JS than semi-working/not working on most devices. Also faking the example with media queries is easy with plain css, my solution is content independent!

Comment: Great answer. I do wish this was possible only via CSS. In fact, I'm a bit disappointed it isn't - a lot of HTML and CSS seems a bit ad-hoc. Perhaps that is a symptom of having evolved over such a long period of time.

Answer (score 6):

Another variant with pure JS

```js
window.addEventListener('load', collapse);
window.addEventListener('resize', collapse);

function collapse() {
  var parents = document.querySelectorAll('.parent');
  var children;
  var width;
  for (var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
    parents[i].classList.remove('collapsed');
    width = 0;
    children = parents[i].children;
    for (var j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
      width += children[j].offsetWidth;
    }
    if (width > parents[i].offsetWidth) {
      parents[i].classList.add('collapsed');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.parent,
.child {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.collapsed {
  display: block;
}

.child {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Some thing one</div>
  <div class="parent child">
    <div class="child">Some inner</div>
    <div class="child">long thing</div>
    <div class="child">two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">Thing three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP in question: `I'm looking for a solution that uses only HTML and CSS (or only uses JavaScript very lightly) since my intended use-case is to use this pretty heavily in automatically generated HTML documentation pages` so this is not a solution

Comment: So do you think this script is not light enough?

Comment: @dippas I actually think this is the optimal approach. No way this could be solved without JS. And the collapsed() method created with pure JS is a good way of solving it. I would’ve created a jQuery method and bind it to selectors, but we are not allowed to assume the OP is using any third part JS libraries. Good job, sam

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use `@media` queries to alternate between

```
display: block
```

and

```
display: inline-block
```

**Working Example:**

```css
.long-row {
display: inline-block;
width: 200px;
padding-left: 4px;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 32px;
border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 801px) {
    .long-row {
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .long-row {
        display: block;
        border-top: none;
    }

    div:first-of-type.long-row {
        border-top: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .long-row {
    }

    .short-row {
        display: block;
        margin-left: -4px;
        padding-left: 4px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
    
    span:last-of-type.short-row {
        border-bottom: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="long-row">Some thing one</div>

<div class="long-row">
<span class="short-row">Some inner</span>
<span class="short-row">long thing</span>
<span class="short-row">two</span>
</div>

<div class="long-row">Thing three</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Before getting to the script, there are couples of notes that should be considered :

At my actual state of my knowledge, this cannot be done using only CSS. So the question is how to do this using pure JavaScript with the best performance possible? And I've come up with some guidelines :

- using `for` loops as they are the fastest using cache of the number of iterations
- minimizing functions calls whenever possible

**Avoiding :**

- recursive functions
- [].foreach constructs
- DOM access whenever possible

In addition to that it can be nested to any level

**The idea:**

The script takes all elements, force them into a single line, and see if there is not enough space, it make them displayed on top of each other, otherwise they stayed on the same line.

It does this every time the document's markup is loaded, and when the window is resized.

https://jsfiddle.net/nasdao/qzdtr9ym/

Comment: I've effectively tested this against jQuery and find it almost threefold faster.

Comment: Tested against a working Js solution that relies on getting the total width of the children to compare them with the width of the container and find this solution to be a lot faster. When in doubt, try jsperf.com. The reason for this is that my method works with the container rather than getting into the details of the style of the children

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in  my comment you can make use of flexbox, here is a demonstration of how you wanted.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: flex-end;
}

.flex-item {
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  margin: 2px;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  border:3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">Something One</div>
  <div class="flex-container" style="border:2px solid black">
     <div class="flex-item">Something 2</div>
     <div class="flex-item">Something random3</div>
     <div class="flex-item">Some 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">Something Five</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not quite what I want (I'd like to go straight from having the all items on one row to all items stacked, skipping the step where two items are on one row and the third on a another row), but nonetheless helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @Alec oh, I didn't quite get your question firsthand.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it with using display:flex;

For example:

```css
 .horz_cont {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        align-content: flex-end;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        padding: 4px;
    }
    
    .horz_cont .horz_cont {
       border: none;
       padding: 0;
    }
    
    .item {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        margin: 4px;
        padding: 4px;
        height: 50px;
        font-size: 34px;
        font-weight: bold;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
```

```html
<div class="horz_cont">
  <div class="item">Some thing one</div>
  <div class="horz_cont">
     <div class="item">Some inner</div>
     <div class="item">long thing</div>
     <div class="item">two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="horz_cont">
     <div class="item">Thing three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is this any different than the existing answer? Also, see my comment on the first answer - your solution suffers from the same problem.

Comment: There is the one way that I know to solve this problem. It doesn't matter for me who first.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way to do it at every screen size in pure css. I need a bit of javascript (easier with jquery)

1. Those elements are inline blocks.
2. For each group of siblings elements check if the top position of the last child is the same that top position of the first child (if so, they are in the same line).
3. If not the same top position, add a class to make them blocks again (spite of inline-blocks).

Works well with n-nested levels and it's reasonably light javascript. (plus no media querys, any number of items per level, no loops with "trying to fit", probably the widest browser support...)

```js
$(function() {
 $('div.line:first-child ~ div.line:last-child').each(
  function(){
    if( $(this).position().top != $(this).siblings(":first-child").position().top ){
      $(this).parent().addClass("breaks")
    }
  }
 );
});
```

```css
div{outline:1px solid red;}

.line{display:inline-block;}
.breaks > .line{display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="line">Some thing one</div>
<div class="line">
  <div class="line">Some inner</div>
  <div class="line">longest thing</div>
  <div class="line">two</div>
</div>
<div class="line">this is long Thing three</div>
</div>
```

EDIT: a second option with same logic, but using selector for the "group" of items -not the items themselves-, with better performance and no jquery

```js
window.addEventListener('load', breaklines);

function breaklines() {
  var groups = document.querySelectorAll('.group');
  for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
    if(groups[i].children[0].offsetTop != groups[i].children[ groups[i].children.length - 1].offsetTop){
      groups[i].classList.add('breaks');
    }else{
      groups[i].classList.remove('breaks');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
div.group > div{outline:2px dotted red;}
div.group div.group > div{outline:2px solid green;}


.group > div {display:inline-block}
.group.breaks > div {display:block}
```

```html
<div class="group">
<div>Some thing one</div>
<div class="group">
  <div>Some inner</div>
  <div>longest thing</div>
  <div>two</div>
</div>
<div>this is long Thing three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is a really nice solution! But what if the children are aligned by middle or by bottom? I suggest to compare that: the bottom of the first child must be lower than the top of the last child, else add the "breaks" class.

Comment: Depending on the use case should be adapted. 'Extreme cases', like having inline images, negative bottom margins, different font sizes... can make it much more complex. Being in the same line is "equal top position" for THIS case, for other cases a could be better a different one. Your proposed test for certain cases can fail (as mine for others). A 3x size icon in last item, wrapping in two lines, will give you the top of the last one over the bottom of the first (if I understood your test) . Anyway thanks for your opinion, I'll rethink about the test considering your point of view.

Answer (score -1):

You could try using media queries on the screen sizes, such that when the inner content of the middle flexbox exceeds its container, you can write CSS that only applies to that scenario.

It's important to also add the viewport tag to head of your html:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Open the example in full screen and resize the viewport of the browser to see how the elements pop around.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: flex-end;
}
.flex-item, .inner-flex-item {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 50px;
  border:3px solid black;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1180px) {
  .flex-item {
    width: 80%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .inner-flex-item {
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">Something One</div>
  <div class="flex-container" style="border:2px solid black">
    <div class="inner-flex-item">Some inner</div>
    <div class="inner-flex-item">long thing</div>
    <div class="inner-flex-item">two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">Thing three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This suffers from the same problems as all the other existing solutions (and some more): my question explicitly specifies that I expect the three side by side items to stack vertically as soon as there isn't space for all three - not to start wrapping and have two items on one row and the third on another row.

Comment: I've made an edit to (rather crudely) show how that can also be accomplished via media queries. I think there is a possible solution for your question to be found by playing around with these.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically calculate the values `max-width` based on the contents? Since I intend to generate a lot of these programmatically, that seems like something that would be important.

Comment: I think I see what you are getting at; you want to set the media query breakpoint to equal the combined widths of the 3 things so it's at that point it snaps into the second configuration. I'm not exactly sure how to do that, but that does not mean there isn't a way!